# How to check if a database exists on MongoDB without using mongClient.getDatabaseNames()

Tags: mongodb

we configured our mongobd to forbid the “listdatabase” (i.e,  mongClient.getDatabaseNames()) feature for privacy reasons

I would like to check whether a database exists in MongoDB without using mongClient.getDatabaseNames().

If I use, mongoClient.getDB("mydb"), mongodb creates a new db instance which can't help to check whether dbname exist.

Any suggestions please?

We have a common 'ui connection wizard' to connect to different mongodb servers which have different authentications. This wizard has to verify "dabase_name" field, whether user entered correct database name. In this case, "listDatabase"( i.e client.getDataBaseNames()) can't be used as authentication fails or "use db"(i.e, client.getDB()) can't be used as it creates an new db instance.

Answer (score 3):

When do you consider a database to exist? Why do you need to do this check? MongoDB creates a database when it creates a collection in the database, which happens when data is inserted, an index is create, or the collection is created with `db.createCollection()`. A reasonable condition for a database not to exist is that it contains no collections. Another reasonable condition would be that all the collections in it contains do not contain data. You can check for the former using `db.getCollectionNames()`, the latter by examining `db.<collection>.count()` for each collection. Yet a third condition might be that the database has zero storage size, which you could check with `db.stats()`.

In your situation where `getDatabaseNames()` is forbidden for security reasons, you should control access to the databases with security and worry about authorization, not existence. If a database exists, it should be restricted to the appropriate users and roles so that if another user tries to interact with that database, they will be rejected.

Comment: We have a common 'ui connection wizard' to connect to different mongodb servers which have different authentications. This wizard has to verify "dabase_name" field, whether user entered correct database name. In my case, "listDatabase" can't be used as authentication fails or "use db (client.getDB())" can't be used as it creates an new db instance.